# Why can't I import Flutter 'responsive_framework' package?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I need to use the Flutter 'responsive framework' package for my app to be more responsive to different device sizes, but I am unable to import the package on my MacBook even though it's working on my Windows.

First I run `flutter pub add responsive_framework` in my Flutter terminal. This adds `responsive_framework: ^0.2.0` in my dependencies in the `pubspec.yaml` file. However, when I import `import 'package:responsive_framework/responsive_framework.dart';` in my `main.dart` file, I get an error saying that:

> "Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:responsive_framework/responsive_framework.dart'. Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist.

How do I fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try `flutter clean` then `flutter run`.